# How to sample Renderbuffer depth information and process it in CPU code, without causing an impact on performance?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to sample a few fragments' depth data that I need to use in my client code (that runs on CPU).
I tried a glReadPixel() on my FrameBuffer Object, but turns out it stalls the render pipeline as it transfers data from Video Memory to Main Memory through the CPU, thus causes unbearable lag (please, correct me if I am wrong).

I read about Pixel Buffer objects, that we can use them as copies of other buffers, and very importantly, perform glReadPixel() operation without stalling the performance, but not without compromising to use outdated information. (That's OK for me.)

But, I am unable to understand about how to use Pixel Buffers.
What I've learnt is we need to sample data from a texture to store it in a PixelBuffer. But I am trying to sample from a Renderbuffer, which I've read is not possible.

So here's my problem - I want to sample the depth information stored in my Render Buffer, store it in RAM, process it and do other stuff, without causing any issues to the Rendering Pipeline. If I use a depth texture instead of a renderbuffer, i don't know how to use it for depth testing.
Is it possible to copy the entire Renderbuffer to the Pixelbuffer and perform read operations on it?

Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glReadPixels can also transfer from a framebuffer to a standard GPU side buffer object. If you generate a buffer and bind it to the GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER target, the data pointer argument to glReadPixels is instead an offset into the buffer object. (So probably should be 0 unless you are doing something clever.)

Once you've copied the pixels you need into a buffer object, you can transfer or map or whatever back to the CPU at a time convenient for you.